# How to achieve JavaScript Object inheritance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create a new JavaScript object based on an existing JavaScript object.
Till now my research led me to jQuery extend function.

example:

```
var object1 = {
    name:'same name',
    age:'1',
    occupation:'programmer'
}
var object2 = {
    name:'same new name'
}
```

Now, when I call:

```
$.extend({},object1,object2);
```

it works perfectly, my problem is when I have object member within the object!

```
var object1 = {
    name:'same name',
    age:19,
    occupation:'programmer',
    parent:{
        name:'parent name',
        age:35
    }
}
var object2 = {
    name:'same new name',
    parent:{
        age:40
    }
}
```

Now, when I call

```
$.extend({},object1,object2);
```

object1.parent is:

```
{
    age:40
}
```

I want it to be:

```
{
    name:'same new name',
    age:40
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Btw, your solution has nothing to do with inheritance, it's simply copying properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use **deep** parameter for jQuer.extend() method, your code should be:

```
$.extend(true,{},object1,object2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to perform a deep extend

```
$.extend(true, {},object1,object2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force `$.extend` to do a deep copy like so:

```
$.extend(true, {},object1,object2);
```

although `$.extend` doesn't create an inheritance hierarchy so much as it just copies properties.